# JBoss Native Connector in JBoss 4.2.x

Tags: jboss, native

I would like to configure JBoss 4.2.x to utilize the [JBoss Web Native Connectors](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-9) instead of the default Ajp processor. This is in order to avoid a bug in the Jboss 4.2.x Ajp processor of which results in many hung threads and performance hits.

I cannot seem to find any installation instructions on this. Does anyone have any info how to do this?

Does the latest Native Connector from the download site [1](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-9) work for my old version of JBoss?

If I can find a step-by-step guide, I will publish it in a wiki for anyone else in the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0)  Stop jboss

1)  Please download this link:

http://downloads.jboss.org/jbossnative//2.0.10.GA/jboss-native-2.0.10-linux2-i64-ssl.tar.gz

This will contain a directory with

jboss-native-2.0.10-linux2-i64-ssl/bin
jboss-native-2.0.10-linux2-i64-ssl/licenses

2)  Merge these directories on top of your jboss-4.2.3.GA directory.

3)  Start jboss.